# passenger error "Could not find activesupport-3.2.1 in any of the sources"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, capistrano, activesupport

I just managed to upload my rails app files via capistrano into my ec2 instance but now i am getting some errors when i try to access the web page:

**Ruby (Rack) application could not be started**

```
Error message:
    Could not find activesupport-3.2.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
Exception class:
    PhusionPassenger::UnknownError
```

i installed activesupport and re-deployed it into the server... problem still persists... any thoughts?

Comment: try adding it to the gemfile and bundle install on server, maybe it will work

Comment: already did on client, do you mean on server?

Comment: yeah, do a bundle install, or a bundle update, on SERVER

Comment: i did that and it seems to work... i guess there should be an option to make this when you do cap deploy... anyway now i have to find out how to upload the database on production via cap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the gem to the Gemfile?

Did you check Gemfile.lock to your repository?

Did you tell your capfile to execute `bundle install --deployment` or `bundle install`?

Comment: what i did is that from the client machine i downloaded the gem, added it into the gemfile and then uploaded it via capistrano into the ec2 server... is there anything else than i missed?

Comment: Typically, bundle install should take care of the dependency of gems. On my server: 

rm Gemfile.lock > /dev/null;
bundle install --no-deployment > /dev/null;
bundle install --deployment > /dev/null;
bundle install > /dev/null;